# How to read ECS instance tag information from an app running inside docker conainer

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, amazon-ecs

I am trying to read my EC2 instance tags (Key and value) from inside an app which is deployed as ECS service. So I am inside the docker container and I am trying to read the host instance *meta-data.*

I checked this documentation in AWS but this only talks about the details on reading the EC2 instance meta-data by doing an SSH. But I am not going to do the SSH. So these API does not work inside Docker containers.

However I found a way to read the *meta-data* info from inside the docker container from my app. E.g. `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/`

You can run these commands inside the Docker containers running as ECS service to get some information on your meta-data.

**However, how do I read the tags on my EC2 host instances which runs my docker container?**

> I like to read a tag called *Environment* on my EC2 host instance
>   inside the running docker container.

Comment: I found a way to get EC2 instance-id by doing ```curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id```

Comment: Also there is some documentation available to read tags - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTags.html

Answer (score 0):

Install an API SDK in the ECS container

Ensure that the container instance has read permissions for ec2:ResourceTag on the instance that you are interested in.  I assume from your question that this is the container instance itself?

Then use the API SDK call for loading the tags

In the shell AWS CLI the `aws ec2 describe-tags` call is probably what you want, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-tags.html